# how to pass object in child component to the parents in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

i'm looking to make a mulit step from in angularJS 1.5x and here is my file format

```
-events
--events.component.js
--events.controller.js
-form.component.js
-form.controller.js
```

in my form.component.js i am using UI router to route to the different parts of the form..

```
var createForm = {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/event/form.html'
    };

    angular
        .module('components.event')
        .component('createEvent', createEvent)
        .config(function($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('form', {
                    url: '/form',
                    component: 'createForm'
                })
                // nested states 
                .state('form.events', {
                    url: '/events',
                    component: 'createEvents'
                })
        });
```

in the parent controller(form.controller.js) i have an object $scope.formData:

```
function EventController($scope) {

        $scope.formData = {};

    }

    angular
        .module('components.event')
        .controller('EventController', EventController);
```

I want to access $scope.formData from my events controller. I've tried using $scope.$parent.formData in events.controller.js which haven't worked for me yet

```
function EventController($scope) {

        $scope.parentformData = $scope.$parent.formData;

    }

    angular
        .module('components.event')
        .controller('EventController', EventController);
```

any ideas on how i can do this?

Comment: A resolve function may inject the results of other resolves from ancestor states, or from other resolves on the same state. See [UI-Router for AngularJS (1.x) #resolve](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/hellogalaxy#resolve)

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code is helpful !

```
//No need to pass the .js file name.
//Just pass the name / element of your controller.

//eg:
    // assuming this is your controller definition/declaration inside form.controller.js
    function formController($scope) {
        // code insde controller
    }

    // assuming this code is written inside events.controller.js 
    function EventController($scope) {

       var formControllerScope = angular.element(formController).scope();
       console.log(formControllerScope.formData);
    }
```